# How to store and convert IP addresses in H2?

Tags: database, ip, h2

What is the best field type and length for storing IP (IPv4) addresses in a H2 database?
The input is text e.g. "X.X.X.X".
In MySQL there are some handy functions for converting IP data:

```
INET_ATON and INET_NTOA
```

Are there any equivalents in H2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to index it and unless you store really a lot of IP addresses, I would use `VARCHAR`.

If you store many entries, you could use `BINARY`.

You could create [user defined functions](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) in the H2 database for `INET_ATON` and `INET_NTOA`.